# Executar uma procedure enquanto o componente estiver pressionado

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

Tenho uma aplicação multi-device feita no Delphi-XE8, nela eu tenho uma imagem (`TImage`) de foguete e outras 2 de setas, gostaria que o foguete se desloca-se no eixo X da tela (`Position.X`), porém com o código atual o usuário teria que ficar apertando diversas vezes para alterar a posição desse componente.

**Existe algum método ou event que seja ativado enquanto o usuário fique com o dedo pressionando o botão de seta?**

Segue o código que tenho atualmente:

```
unit Game;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Layouts,
  FMX.ExtCtrls, FMX.Objects;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ShipImage: TImage;
    ImageRightArrow: TImage;
    ImageLeftArrow: TImage;
    procedure ImageLeftArrowMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
    procedure ImageRightArrowMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}




procedure TForm1.ImageRightArrowMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
   ShipImage.Position.X := (ShipImage.Position.X + 10);

end;

procedure TForm1.ImageLeftArrowMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
   ShipImage.Position.X := (ShipImage.Position.X - 10);
end;

end.
```

E uma imagem da parte da Unit que me importa:

[image: UnitGame]

Como podem ver agora uso o evento MouseDown, porém como disse, ele requer que o usuário fique clicando diversas vezes para ser executado.

Answer (score 1):

Em vez de moveres no evento **MouseDown**, podes ter um timer(ou outro processo semelhante) a fazer o movimento.
Esse timer é activado no **MouseDown** e desactivado no **MouseUp**.

Assim o user pressiona a tecla, o timer liga e começa a mover o objecto, até que o user retire o dedo e o timer é parado.

Exemplo:

```
var fDirection:integer;

procedure TForm2.ImgLeftMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
   Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
   //Vai para a esquerda
   fDirection:=-1;
   //liga  o timer
   TmrMovimento.Enabled:=true;
end;

procedure TForm2.ImgLeftMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
   Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
   //Pára  o timer
   TmrMovimento.Enabled:=false;
end;

procedure TForm2.ImgRightMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
   Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  //Vai para a direita
  fDirection:=1;
  //liga  o timer
  TmrMovimento.Enabled:=true;
end;

procedure TForm2.ImgRightMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
 Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
   //Pára  o timer
   TmrMovimento.Enabled:=false;
end;

procedure TForm2.TmrMovimentoTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Move para a direçao pretendida
  ShipImage.Position.X := (ShipImage.Position.X + (10*fDirection));
end;
```

Agora é uma questão de ajustar o numero de pixeis a mover e o intervalo do timer para ter a velocidade/fluidez que pretende, neste caso usei timer com 30ms.

Comment: Pode colocar um exemplo?

Comment: editado com exemplo

Comment: +1 vou ver se ele serve pro meu problema amanhã, mas muito obrigado já